# JavaFX: SplitPane changes divider position on resize if there are items inside

Tags: java, javafx

I have the following code:

```
public class JavaFxApplication2 extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        SplitPane splitPane=new SplitPane();
        VBox vBox1=new VBox();
        vBox1.setStyle("-fx-background-color: red");
        VBox vBox2=new VBox();
        vBox2.setStyle("-fx-background-color: blue");
        splitPane.getItems().add(vBox1);
        splitPane.getItems().add(vBox2);
        splitPane.getDividers().get(0).setPosition(0);
        Scene scene=new Scene(splitPane, 200, 400);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

This is the output when I run application:
[image]
Now I resize and make stage larger:
[image]
As you see divider position now is not 0. How to disable divider position changing on resizing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All the nodes contained by the `SplitPane` become resized by default, hence the "wandering divider".

You can use [`setResizableWithParent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/SplitPane.html#setResizableWithParent-javafx.scene.Node-java.lang.Boolean-) to avoid resizing the left `VBox`:

```
SplitPane.setResizableWithParent(vBox1, false);
```

> Sets a node in the SplitPane to be resizable or not when the SplitPane
>   is resized. **By default all node are resizable. Setting value to false
>   will prevent the node from being resized.**

If you do not want the right `VBox` to be resized, this method has to be called for that node also.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I do want the vbox be resizable. I don't want the divider postion change its value. Look, when I run application, both vbox are resizable, but the divider position is 0.

Comment: The `VBox`es remain resizable, they are just not resized automatically (the divider will not move) when the splitpane itself is resized.